# Multipart File Upload: How to Handle FileHeaders

Tags: go, multipartform-data, multipart

I need to read a multipart form file. I'm passing custom req obj to handler function rather than the http.request object, I'm using Gorilla Mux.
Handler Signature is something like this:

```
func handlerFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, cR *custReqObj)
```

I'm accessing it like this:

```
fileHeaders := cR.MultipartForm.File["file"]
fileHeader := fileHeaders[0]
fileName := fileHeader.Filename
file, err := fileHeader.Open()
```

Since I dont have a request object, i cannot do this:

```
request.FormFile["file"]
```

I have gone through http.FormFile, it also returns the first file header.

```
if r.MultipartForm != nil && r.MultipartForm.File != nil {
        if fhs := r.MultipartForm.File[key]; len(fhs) > 0 {
            f, err := fhs[0].Open()
            return f, fhs[0], err
        }
}
```

**Is my approach correct and in which cases I'll need to consider multiple file headers?**
I'd really appreciate if you can shed some light on what is file header and how does multipart package work in golang.

Comment: How do you define `custReqObj`? I think you need to embed/include `Request` object in your custom request, so you can use methods defined in `http.Request`. As stated in [the doc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormFile), `Request.FormFile` return only the first file. If you have multiple files or multiple section, you should use [`Request.MultipartReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.MultipartReader) to read each part, then call `Part.FileName` or `Part.FormName` to access corresponding data.

Answer (score 3):

You should call `req.ParseMultipartForm(SOME_SIZE)` before using `req.MultipartForm`; something like:

```
err := req.ParseMultipartForm(SOME_SIZE)
if err != nil {
    // ...
}

formdata := req.MultipartForm
for k, files := range formdata.File {
    for i := range files {
        file, err := files[i].Open()
        defer file.Close()
        if err != nil {
            // ...
        }

        fp := filepath.Join(someDirWithProperAccess, files[i].Filename)
        out, err := os.Create(fp)
        defer out.Close()
        if err != nil {
            // ...
        }

        _, err = io.Copy(out, file)

        if err != nil {
            logrus.Error(err)
            return
        }
    }
}
```